# MySQL query with both inner joins and left joins?

Tags: mysql

I had a problem where I need to query multiple tables, but one of them needed to be LEFT JOIN as well as my normal inner joins, so I could see nulls in the result set, if there were missing values.

Took me forever to get it right, so I am posting the answer below.

Comment: Joining isn't a commutative operation so you'll get a different result on a different join order for the same tables. Show us the sample data/code to get it straight.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @Kondybas - `INNER JOIN` is commutative and associative; `LEFT JOIN` is not.  In fact, the Optimizer will [usually] try all permutations of Inner Joins to decide what table to start with, then [usually] use "Nested Loop Join" for the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from a Drupal site, which is why the table names are weird.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (field_data_field_due_date a, node n)
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_sent_due_date_email b on a.entity_id = b.entity_id
WHERE 
  a.entity_id = n.nid
  AND a.field_due_date_value IS NOT NULL
  AND b.field_sent_due_date_email_value IS NULL
  AND n.type = 'task';
```

Just FYI: What I am trying to accomplish with this query is I am looking for tasks where the due date is set, but no "due date email" has been sent yet.

So to explain a little-- the tables listed next to my FROM are in parenthesis, and you can see in the WHERE clause which fields I am joining them on.

The secret that took me so long is this: Notice I place my LEFT JOIN just under that.  This allows me to get back "NULL" for the values in the table "field_data_field_sent_due_date_email" if it doesn't match on entity_id.  In this way I can test if a value is NOT there by testing for NULL.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I don't see any right joins?

Comment: Ahh, you're right.  I meant to say "inner join" instead of right join.  Will edit now.

Comment: It's a Bad Idea™ to mix explicit join syntax with the old-school Cartesian join syntax in the same statement (or use the old style syntax at all).

Comment: You're probably right, but old code and old habits are both hard to let go of!

Comment: Not just weird, but also verbose and clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

re Title question:  Yes, you can mix them.  However...

Tips:

- Put `JOINs` first and `LEFT JOINs` last.
- If you choose to violate the above tip, use parentheses to group JOINs, but that is confusing.  [This may have been part of your problem.]  Example:

  ```
  FROM (a LEFT JOIN b ON ...) JOIN c ON ...
  ```

versus

```
  FROM a LEFT JOIN (b ON ... JOIN c ON ...)
```

- Turn `RIGHT JOIN` into `LEFT JOIN` (else my head will spin like an owl's)
- In MySQL, the keywords `INNER`, `OUTER`, `CROSS` have no impact.  In particular, `INNER JOIN` is treated identically to `JOIN`.
- To help with readability, use `ON` for specifying how tables are *related*; use `WHERE` for "filtering".  (The Optimizer treats `ON` and `WHERE` as equivalent for `INNER JOIN`; not for `LEFT JOIN`.)  [This may have been part of your problem.]
- The pattern for finding just the rows of `a` that have no corresponding row in `b`:

  ```
    FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b  ON a.foo = b.foo
    WHERE ...
      AND b.id IS NULL
  ```